# external css is working partially

Tags: html, css

In my code **class "slides"** is working through external css link but class header is working through inline css only.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="slides">
<div class="header" style="width:100%; background-color:#630;"><img src="gz1.gif">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
head,body{background-color:#CCC; margin:0; padding:0;;}

.slides{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom,red,white);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(bottom,red,white);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom,red,white);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,red,white);
    background:linear-gradient(bottom,red,white);
}

.header{position:fixed;}
```

I want to work **class "header"** code from external link instead of inline code...

Answer (score -1):

To avoid inline css in your code, update your html and css like below:

Here we will remove inline styling from header div..

```
<div class="header"><img src="gz1.gif"></div>
```

And we will add the inline style of header div in the style.css like so...

```
head,body{
background-color:#CCC;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.slides{
overflow:hidden;
background:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom,red,white);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(bottom,red,white);
background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom,red,white);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,red,white);
background:linear-gradient(bottom,red,white);
}
.header{
position:fixed;
width:100%; 
background-color:#630;
}
```

Comment: i have tried it earlier but so but on adding this in **style.css** it is not working. It is working only on inline @Binita

Comment: Your style.css has two semi colons at the end of 
head,body{background-color:#CCC; margin:0; padding:0;;}...
please remove and check it...
head,body{background-color:#CCC; margin:0; padding:0;}

Comment: I have remove one semicolons ; but same problem. I want **background-color:#630;** to be applied for full width i.e. 100% through style.css but is showing red color which i have applied in **linear-gradient**...If i am applying it in inline css then it is working, but i don't want to use this method..

Comment: In that case, you can try updating .header{background:none; background-color:#0630;}